# Сложности с jsp и контроллером

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Есть класс "Папка", папки содержат ссылки на другие папки + имя. Хранится все в БД. Это дерево нужно вывести в браузере.

Вывожу родительские папки, после нажатия на них, ниже должны подгружаться дети.
Не знаю как написать контроллер под эту ситуацию и, как выводить дочерние папки на jsp.

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listFolder(Model model){

   model.addAttribute("folders", this.folderService.getMainFolders());


    return "list";
}
@RequestMapping("getChild/{id}")
public String getChilds(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("childList", this.folderService.getChildsByPerentId(id));


    return "listChild";
}
```

Кусок jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${folders}" var="folder">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="getChild/${folder.id}" target="_self">${folder.title}</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${childList}" var="childFolder">
        <td><a href="getChild/${childFolder.id}" target="_self">${childFolder.title}</a></td>
        </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Как должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Class.java

```
@RequestMapping("getChild/{id}")
public String getChilds(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("childList", this.folderService.getChildsByPerentId(id));
    model.setViewName("name jsp file");


    return model;
}
```